# CoroutineWorker stuck in the Running state and refuses to finish except when restarted

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-workmanager

I have a CoroutineWorker which uploads a file in the background, the problem is that it refuses to return Result.success() (or any Result) and keeps stuck in the Running state even though I have a log statement just before the return statement and it executes fine. When I restart the app though the worker relaunches and this time it responds to return statemnts

Any idea why this might be happening?